# Каким образом решить уравнение вида ax + bx + cz = n

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте, какой нужно написать алгоритм для решения уравнения вида ax + by + cz = n, где a, b, c и n известны?

Comment: Никакой. Для однозначного решения задачи с тремя неизвестными нужно три уравнения. Учите мат. часть.

Comment: Алгоритм перебора x, y, z. Только решений будет много.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, формально, в текущей постановке, количество решений представляет собой бесконечное множество.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вы бы могли его отправить?

Comment: @droft1312, как бы `x = 0, y = 0, z = n/c` будет является решением... только в текущей постановке задача **не имеет смысла**!

Comment: @droft1312 написать его за вас и просто так вам отправить? Спасибо, не надо.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора

Answer (score 3):

Так как в вашем уравнении (`ax + by + cz = n`) присутствуют 3 неизвестных, то вам требуется по крайней мере еще 2 уравнения для решения, т.е. по факту у вас должна иметься система из 3-ех уравнений для выведения каждой из неизвестных.

После же составления системы уравнений, вы можете реализовать её решение, например, [методом Гаусса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0) или [Крамера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0).

Или ваш вопрос затрагивает какие-то иные аспекты (например, выведение зависимости одной неизвестной от другой/других)?

Comment: Черт, у меня в мыслях было, что можно каким-нибудь перебором решить данное уравнение.

Comment: Ну, например в случае натуральных чисел, решений может и не быть вовсе. `2x + 3y + 4z = 1`.

Comment: @droft1312 Скорее всего, в общем случае должно существовать бесконечное множество решений.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, не скорее всего, а абсолютно точно. множество решений не ограничено.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, Ха, ну-ка приведите любое решение для 0x+0y+0z=1? Вангую, что это вариант классической задачи составление суммы из набора монет.

Comment: @andy.37 Поймали, хороший контр-пример!) Как бы то ни было, при хотя бы одном из коэффициентов a, b, c не равных нулю, множество решений не ограничено. Хотя, наверное, могут быть и другие интересные частные случаи...

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, не-а)))) 1x + 0y + 0z = 1))))

Comment: @andy.37, это не натуральные числа.

Comment: @Denis, это неизвестно.

Comment: @andy.37, `1x + 0y + 0z = 1` подходят решения (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3).... множество решений  не ограничено.

Comment: @sercxjo, да, теперь я это вижу) но это всего лишь частный случай